# Confused about PL/SQL snippet with dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

This snippet runs w/o errors unless I uncomment `for` loop, in which case I getting

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 12, column 41:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

My question is why error occurs with for loop uncommented?

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  v_sql varchar2(2000);
  v_tmp number;
begin
  dbms_output.enable(null);
  v_sql := 'CREATE TABLE tmp_bank_codes (name varchar2(256), code varchar2(256))';
  dbms_output.put_line('Will do ' || v_sql);
  execute immediate v_sql;
  v_sql := 'INSERT INTO tmp_bank_codes (name, code) VALUES (''Bank of America'', ''BOANY (NY)'')';
  dbms_output.put_line('Will do ' || v_sql);
  execute immediate v_sql;
--for bank_code in (select name, code from tmp_bank_codes) loop
--  select 1 into v_tmp from dual;
--end loop;
execute immediate 'drop table tmp_bank_codes';
rollback;

end;
/
```

Comment: My question is why error occurs with `for` loop uncommented.

Comment: It's not a good idea to create tables on-the-fly in Oracle. You're better off creating `tmp_bank_codes` once and for all as a Global Temporary Table, then you won't need to recreate or drop it (plus, it will make this code safe for concurrent use as well.)

Comment: Thanks to all for suggestions, I just playing with more advanced PL/SQL. In the end I settled for more static code, w/o any dynamic SQL here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because you use dynamic sql to create the table and the in the for loop you are using the table.
While compiling the procedure, compiler doesnt know that you have created the table with dynamic sql

Here are your options:

1. make the for loop also with Dynamic SQL
2. change the dymamic sql to create the table to normal sql statement

**I would prefer the second option, as the dynamic sql will not take the cached execution plans, thus slows down the query**

For option 1 you could do this, replace your commented code part with the following

```
v_sql :='for bank_code in (select name, code from tmp_bank_codes) loop
        select 1 into v_tmp from dual;
        end loop';
execute immediate v_sql;
```

Comment: Can you spare a hint how can it be rewritten to fix this?

Comment: what higher-level goal are you trying to acheive doing this? this is not a common oracle approach to create tables at runtime

Comment: Btw, it's very annoying for Oracle to report ordinal of problematic line with one-off error every now and then.

Comment: @downVoter:- Please leave a comment

Comment: @JoeGJoseph I'm not the downvoter, but dynamic 'loop' you proposed still gives (different) error.

Comment: @JoeGJoseph first of all, this snippet won't work. what you are trying to do would probably be something like `v_sql := 'select name, code from tmp_bank_codes'; execute immediate v_sql bulk collect into (collection of tmp_bank_codes%rowtype)`. second, I do believe runtime table generation and its further processing is a bad, bad practice (at least if we talk about oracle), which shouldn't be encouraged.

Comment: @beherenow Joe has stated explicitly that he prefers non-dynamic creation of tables as well.

Answer (score 3):

This is a parser error. `tmp_bank_codes` doesn't exist at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

First the engine tries to compile your anonymous script. In this first step `tmp_bank_codes` table does not exists.

A solution would be something like

```
execute immediate `select 1 from tmp_bank_codes where rownum = 1` into v_tmp;
```